# how to form validation unique

Tags: python, django, validation

Please tell me. I created a form in which you can select more than 1 artist for one order. Somehow it was made so that if the user mistakenly selected the same artist several times when saving, the duplication was removed. But how can you make sure that the user knows about this, that is, that it was something like “you selected the same artist several times”?

```
class JrtnPerson(models.Model):
    rtn = models.ForeignKey(Drtn, verbose_name='Подразделение Ростехнадзора', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Имя и Отчество')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    tel_mob = PhoneNumberField(verbose_name="Номер телефона мобильный", blank=True, null=True)
    tel_rab = PhoneNumberField(verbose_name="Номер телефона рабочий", blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Электронная почта", blank=True, null=True)
    # def __str__(self):
    #     return '%s %s' % (self.surname, self.name)
    # def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     if  not self.JrtnPerson.objects.filter(surname=self.surname, name=self.name).exists():
    #         super(self.surname, self.name).save(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('surname',)
        verbose_name = 'Сотрудник Ростехнадзора'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Сотрудники Ростехнадзора'
        unique_together = ('name', 'surname')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(JrtnPerson, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.surname, self.name)
class JrtnCurator(models.Model):
    expertise = models.ForeignKey(Cexpertise, verbose_name='Экспертиза', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    curator = models.ForeignKey(JrtnPerson, verbose_name='Сотрудник Ростехнадзора', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.curator

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('curator',)
        verbose_name = 'Куратор от Ростехнадзора'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Кураторы от Ростехнадзора'
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.__class__.objects.filter(expertise=self.expertise, curator=self.curator).exists():
            super(JrtnCurator, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
           raise ValidationError('Нельязя добавлять одного и того же куратора')
```

Comment: Hi. ✋. Can you please format  the code by using code blocks {} button in edit question form.

Comment: This not django's problem. You should use html to make sure your user only can select an artist once. What is that your template code?

Comment: maybe i can use validators to fix that? or only way is to change html?

Comment: Show us your code for form.

Comment: What you should do is, allow user select an artist only once. So you don't need to remove duplicates and validators.

Comment: and how?) i dont understand

Comment: 1) Don't show them the same artist twice. 2) where is the order model? You need to post that to give a full answer.